# Pause NSTimer to go about screen

Tags: objective-c, xcode, nstimer

i have a slideshow that works with `NSTimer` function calls every 3 seconds and i have a About button when user touch about that goes to another screen:

```
-(IBAction)toAbout:(id)sender
{
    about *ab=[[about alloc] initWithNibName:nil bundle:nil];
    [self presentModalViewController:ab animated:YES];
    [ab release];
}
```

and returns from about screen with this function

```
-(IBAction)aboutButton:(id)sender
{
    [self.parentViewController dismissModalViewControllerAnimated:YES];
}
```

why I can pause the `NSTimer` when I'm go to about screen?
and why I can creat the object that works in slideshow screen and works in about screen too?

Answer (score 1):

There is no method for pausing your timer and it doesn't make sense to call `[timer setFireData:[NSDate distantFuture]]`. Instead, invalidate the timer and create a new one once entering the first view.

Invalidate by saying `[timer invalidate];` and set the timer to nil `timer = nil;`.

Comment: why i can create new if the scene call automaticalli and not run any methods when cold with

Answer (score 0):

To pause the timer you may simply call

```
[timer setFireDate:[NSDate distantFuture]];
```

This does not invalidate the timer but simply avoid that the timer keeps firing.

Comment: but if i return with
 [self.parentViewController dismissModalViewControllerAnimated:YES];
the timer dont run again that stays in paus
and i cant start it in another view

Comment: you can restart it in `viewWillAppear` method